# stack smashing detected terminated. Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

The program outputs as expected (a 5 by 4 matrix), but after that it also outputs:

> *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated Aborted (core dumped)

despite the fact that the program worked as it should.
What is the problem and how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5
#define M 4

void transform(int* buf, int** matr, int n, int m);
void resetMatrix(int** ptr, int n, int m);
void printMatrix(int** mt, int n, int m);

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[N][M];
    int* ptr = (int*)(matrix + N);

    transform(ptr, (int**)matrix, N, M);
    resetMatrix((int**)matrix, N, M);
    printMatrix((int**)matrix, N, M);

    return 0;
}

void resetMatrix(int** ptr, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            ptr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void transform(int* buf, int** matr, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matr[i] = buf + i * m;
    }
}

void printMatrix(int** mt, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            printf("%d ", mt[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to access with `ptr[i][j]` e.g. in `resetMatrix`, the compiler need to know the stride of the matrix. This info is lost when `int[N][M]` is decaying to `int**`.

Comment: So much UB in your code. First one: `int* ptr = (int*)(matrix + N);` after this, `ptr` points to beyond the end of the `matrix` array because the `+ N` is performed in units of the size of `matrix[0]`.

Comment: A side note: I find that representing matices with a 1D array (and managing the indices and stride yourself) is often more convenient overall that using 2D arrays.

Comment: It might be worth it to compile the code with sanitizers enabled, they would spot the errors other have commented on.

Comment: **2D arrays are not double pointers**, nor are they compatible with double pointers.

Comment: The program does not "work[] as it should".  The only evidence I can imagine it producing to make you think it does is the output of `printMatrix()` (as all-zero), but that's very weak.  On the other hand, the stack-smashing message is clear evidence that the program *does not* work as it should.  And I can tell you from reading the code that the program is very, very broken, with multiple sources of undefined behavior, and no reason to expect that its actual behavior would be consistent with the function and variable naming.

Comment: Start by looking up how to pass a 2D array to a function.  There are multiple Q&As on that topic here on SO.  That's not the only problem with your code, but I rate it the biggest one.